# github api Is it possible to view when you joined a specific organization?

Tags: github, github-api, github-api-v3

Pretty much the title. Been looking through the github api but I do not see that endpoint.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so. I'd just look in your email for invitation

Comment: That isnt the use case lol. Trying to view the join date of all people within an org. Not just mine.

Comment: ah, makes sense lol. ive struggled with similar problems but that kind of logging was only available with enterprise at the time.